# Mute webview in android apps

Tags: android, audio, webview, volume, mute

I'm building an app that includes some `WebViews`.

I want to mute one of them (not the whole app or device just that specific `WebView`) I searched but there's no certain answer to this question.
Is there anyone knows how to mute a `WebView` sound in Android?

Comment: what do you mean by mute a `WebView`

Comment: @Akshay Bhat 'AB' disable the sound volume

Comment: please explain your requirement clearly. Post some codes then only we can help you.

Comment: @Gokul Sreenivasan it's clear! I want to disable (mute) the sound of a WebView you can think that WebView plays an audio and I'm gonna mute the WebView.

Answer (score 4):

You can't mute only WebViews volume, but you can mute the whole system volume when you are showing the WebView. Like :

 When you are showing that particular WebView use the below method :

```
public static void mute(Context context) {
    AudioManager mAudioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    int mute_volume = 0;
    mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, mute_volume, 0);
}
```

And when the webView is not shown set max volume Like :

```
public static void unmute(Context context) {
    AudioManager mAudioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    int unmute_volume = mAudioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, unmute_volume, 0);
}
```

If you don't want to set full volume you can get current system volume by

```
mAudioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
```

and save it locally and set it back again when you exit the Webview.

Comment: This works, thanks. However it sets the volume setting of the entire phone, so I think you could make some users angry by doing this.

Comment: That's why you should restore the previous volume level upon user leaves your screen.